# Having trouble using fullaccess parameter with combined string and variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hi I am using the new smbshare to grant full access to a security group. The security group is created dynamically with a script so its like this Write Share {samAccountName}. I managed to combine the variables and strings for that but for the full access parameter it seems different as it does not "="

Here is what I have tried

```
New-SMBShare -Name $_."samAccountName" -Path "C:\Share\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments" -FullAccess "MADE\"Write share" "$($_."samAccountName")""
```

However this results in the error

```
New-SmbShare : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'share bsharetestingpermissions2'.
```

I think the syntax is the problem here

edit i have putting an _ in the group name but that returns

```
New-SmbShare : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'share bsharetestingpermissions2'.
```

Comment: take a look at the syntax hiliting for ` "C:\Share\$($_."samAccountName")\MyDocuments"` and you will see that the nested double quotes are NOT actually nested. [*grin*] you need to fix that.

Comment: if you want to have multiple accounts/groups with `-FullAccess` when setting up the share, you will have to separate them with a `,` . Change : `-FullAccess "MADE\"Write share" "$($_."samAccountName")""` To:  `-FullAccess "MADE\Write share", "$($_.samAccountName)"`

Comment: Hi jrider, the account name is part of the group name so its now Write_share_$samAccountName

Comment: Hi @Lee_Dailey How can i do that they look fine?

Comment: @BilalHabib - take a look at what you get from that line of code. the path is NOT enclosed in quotes ... part is in quotes, then part is NOT in quotes, and finally the last part is in quotes. you need the entire path in quotes. either fix your quoting OR build the string before you use it, store it in a $Var & then use that $Var in your `-Path` parameter.